# How to define dynamic ng-model value for export html template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dynamic, angular-ngmodel

I have object that like this:

```
{"item" : 
     {
      "fieldName":"First Name", 
      "model":"user.firstname", 
      "placeholder":"enter your name"
     }
}
```

Now I want to assign dynamic value for `ng-model` and finally get this result:

```
<div class="items form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label ng-binding">
        First Name
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstname" placeholder="enter your name" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to create a form builder with angularjs template and export it. This is online example:

http://jsbin.com/zanigizako/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: What's your question? The example seems to work just fine.

Comment: I want to export html with `ng-model="user.firstname"` . variable model in user item object equal with `user.firstname`